# Error while concatenating 2 or More List of different type in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 list with data from database using entity framework. I want to concatenate these 3 list to a single list and return in `JSON` format.I tried like this.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public JsonResult GetAllData()
 {
     try
     {
         using (var context = new DbDemo())
         {
             var allData_Tweet = context.ObjTwitterDatas.Take(2).ToList();
             var allData_Youtube = context.ObjTubeDatas.Take(2).ToList();
             var allData_Blogs = context.Objblog.Take(2).ToList();
             var allData = allData_Tweet.Concat(allData_Youtube).Concat(allData_Blogs).ToList();
             return Json(allData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
     }
     catch(Exception)
     {

     }
     return Json("false", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

It returns as

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.Concat(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Comment: did you notice all the three lists are of different types !!!

Comment: @TechieBee Yes all are different type.

Comment: @TechieBee I tried with same type and it runs with no error.

Comment: Yes. because if the types are same, they are compatible. in your case, they are not ,so you need to cast them to the base type(Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can box it.

```
var result = allData_Tweet.Cast<object>().Concat(allData_Youtube.Cast<object>()).Concat(allData_Blogs.Cast<object>());
```

result will be `IEnumerable<object>.`

Then to unbox it, you can use `OfType<T>()`.

```
var myType1 = result.OfType<Type1>();
var myType2 = result.OfType<Type2>();
var myType3 = result.OfType<Type3>();
```

type1,type2 & type 3 is type of ObjTwitterDatas,ObjTubeDatas & Objblog types.